# Stream of unsupported format when the same audio is played a second time

Tags: java, exception, inputstream

When ever this class receives an InputStream to play the first time it works. The second time it plays the same stream I get this exception despite it working fine the first time. Any InputStream the method receives is in .wav format.

```
javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException: Stream of unsupported format
```

I'm not sure how the format can suddenly be unsupported when it worked before. here is the code.

```
package Megalo;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Starter 
{
    private Clip clip;
    public Starter() 
    {
        try 
        {
            clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        } 
        catch (LineUnavailableException e) 
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: Cannot find audio system");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void activate(InputStream song) 
    {
        BufferedInputStream audioSong= new BufferedInputStream(song);
        try 
        {
            clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(audioSong));
            clip.start();
            Thread.sleep((clip.getMicrosecondLength() / 1000) - 1);
            clip.close();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the stack trace

```
javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException: Stream of unsupported format
    at java.desktop/javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(AudioSystem.java:1014)
    at Megalo.Starter.activate(Starter.java:32)
    at Megalo.Player.megalovania(Player.java:29)
    at Megalo.Display.actionPerformed(Display.java:46)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6636)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6401)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5012)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4844)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4918)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4547)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4488)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2762)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4844)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Comment: Does the stream need to be closed?

Comment: If I close the Stream the I get a stream closed IOException when i try to play it again. I also the the problem is with the Stream because I used a File beforehand and it worked several times.

Comment: If you've found a solution, you should wait 21 hours (24 since you posted), submit your own answer, and mark it as correct. That way, you help future visitors to this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you instead send the the string of the file location to the method and create the inpustream there it will work.